# Bootstrap 4 card-columns sometimes display columns different in Chrome than other browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, bootstrap-4

I cannot figure out why these cards in cards-column displays differently on chrome. And they are mostly displaying two columns, but not on all of my pages.

This page specific has the issue with showing only one column, go to the tab "Meny": http://nesthus.no/vossapp/bedrift/voss-pizzeria-kebab

But in Edge and Firefox it displays two columns, as i want it to.

However, another page, on the tab "Meny", http://nesthus.no/vossapp/bedrift/cafe-stationen displays two columns in all browsers correctly including chrome.

Problem showed in Chrome, but working in Edge:
[image: Problem showed in Chrome, but working in Edge:]

But, on another page in Chrome it renders fine:
[image: While, another page in Chrome renders fine:]

Answer (score 1):

I don't have your source code (your website is not working) so I can only guess your structure: http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/80810/. And everything seems to work fine in Chrome by just changing `column-count`.

#### Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)

#### Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)

[image]

#### Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)

[image]

#### Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)

#### Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you are already using

```
#menycol {
column-count: 2;
}
```

Then no need to set display and width , just comment or remove it

```
.card-columns .card {
/* display: inline-block; */
/* width: 100%; */
}
```

Comment: This causes alot of issues with the layout.  breaks the column.

Comment: @hunzaboy column-count is for the textual content, not for the divs, if you are using divs structure, then remove the column-count and use flex or simple width 50% to divide it in 2

Comment: Yeah i agree with that, he doesn't need to use that, but why is it working on other pages. The question was why the different behavior.

Comment: Yes it was there just as a part of many tries to resolve the issue, forgot to remove it.